# How to hook CSS file according to theme selection in the customizer section

Tags: theme-development, javascript, theme-customizer, theme-options

I have added a new area in the Customizer section which allows a user to choose whichever theme colors they want:

[image: New customizer area]

But I don't know how to activate/add CSS files according to the selection.

i.e. add `green.css` if green theme color is selected

or add `blue.css` if blue theme color is selected.

Comment: Look at the code of a theme that already does that. Maybe one of the wp default themes.

Comment: You want to enqueue different css file based on this value? Or add some inline css?

Answer (score 0):

You can access Customizer values with `get_theme_mod()`, so you just need to check the value of your setting before enqueueing stylesheets [the normal way](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/):

```
function wpse_310123_enqueue_scheme_css() {
    $scheme = get_theme_mod( 'theme_scheme' );

    if ( $scheme === 'green' ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-green', get_theme_file_uri( 'green.css' ) );
    } elseif ( $scheme === 'blue') {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-blue', get_theme_file_uri( 'blue.css' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_310123_enqueue_scheme_css' );
```

Note that the above code assumes:

- The name of your Customizer setting is `theme_scheme`. If it's not, change that to whatever your actual setting is.
- The possible values are `green` or `blue`. If they're something else, like `green-theme`, then make sure to change those.
- Your blue.css and green.css files are in the root folder of your theme. If they're not, add the directories to the file name, eg. `get_theme_file_uri( 'assets/css/green.css' )`.